# C++ templated quickSort not working with iterators, error C2061

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, quicksort

I was writing a templated version of the quicksort algorithm for various Containers utilizing iterators, but the following errors made themselves known when I attempted to construct an Object::iterator.

- error C2061 : syntax error : identifier 'iterator'
- error C2780: 'void myQuickSort(Container &)' : expects 1 arguments - 3
  (I believe this error is a result of error C2061)

How can I create an iterator to my templated class Container without the compiler giving me these errors.

My code is written below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>

template<class Itr2Printable>
void printVec(Itr2Printable begin, Itr2Printable end)
{
    // couts containing  Objecorder
    std::cout << "[ ";

    for (begin; begin != end; ++begin)
        std::cout << *begin << " ";


    std::cout << "]";
}

template<class Container>
void myQuickSort(Container& c, Container::iterator begin, Container::iterator end)
{
    Container::iterator mid = begin + distance(begin, end) / 2;

    // inclomplete
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 15, 75, 50, 0, 100, 5 };

    std::cout << "\n\n\tquickSort(";
    printVec(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::cout << ", " << 0 << ", " << vec.size() - 1 << ")\n";

    myQuickSort(vec, vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: You need `typename Container::iterator`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/241631

Answer (score 0):

Very known issue. It is a duplicate, but it is easier for me to type the answer than to look for the duplicate question. Replace

```
void myQuickSort(Container& c, Container::iterator begin, Container::iterator end)
```

with

```
void myQuickSort(Container& c, typename Container::iterator begin, typename Container::iterator end)
```

On a side note, design of your quick sort function is incorrect. If you are expressing your function in term of iterators, do not request the container to be passed to function as well.

Comment: Passing the container by reference was a brain fart.                              . If all that is required it a typename identifier, then:                                  . 1) Why not simply write this?                                                                   . template<class ContainerItr>                                                                  . void myQuickSort(ContainerItr begin, ContainerItr end)

Comment: 2) Is there a benefit to using typename "Container::iterator" instead? . template<class Container> void myQuickSort(typename Container::iterator begin, typename Container::iterator end)

Comment: No benefit whatsoever :) Look into prototype of `std::sort`.